# flutter image widget every time will into errorBuilder function

Tags: flutter

i'm use Image widget and use errorBuilder,As long as an error occurs once, it will enter the errorBuilder every time thereafter，Whether it contains errors or not，I want to enter the errorBuilder only when an error occurs

```
class GirlWidgetState extends State<GirlWidget> {

  String _imgUrl = "https://uploadbeta.com/api/pictures/random/?key=%E6%8E%A8%E5%A5%B3%E9%83%8E&random=96831";

  void refreshGirl() {
    print('触发刷新动作');
    var rmd = new Random();
    setState(() {
      _imgUrl = 'https://uploadbeta.com/api/pictures/random/?key=%E6%8E%A8%E5%A5%B3%E9%83%8E&random=${rmd.nextInt(100000)}';
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('看个美女APP'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: Image.network(_imgUrl,loadingBuilder: (BuildContext context,Widget child,ImageChunkEvent chunkEvent){
          if(chunkEvent==null) {
            return child;
          }
          return Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(
              value: chunkEvent.expectedTotalBytes!=null ? chunkEvent.cumulativeBytesLoaded/chunkEvent.expectedTotalBytes : null
            ),
          );

        },errorBuilder: (BuildContext context,Object info,StackTrace stackTrace) {

          return Center(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Text('图片加载失败',style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 24
                ),),
                Icon(Icons.error,color: Colors.red,)
              ],
            )
          );
        },)
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        tooltip: '换一张',
        child: Icon(Icons.autorenew),
        onPressed: refreshGirl,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: add `print(info)` before calling `return Center(...` - what do you see on the logs?

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. This interface always returns 503 ,thank you!

Comment: your welcome: `503 Service Unavailable`